# Grammatically, comma or period after "no problem", "sure", "okay" and the like

Tags: punctuation, commas, periods, discourse-markers

Grammatically, do we put a comma or period after the phrases / words like "no problem", "sure", "okay", and the like, when responding to a request, or there is no grammatical rule and this is purely a style preference?

What syntactic role do these words play? Are these independent clauses, stand-alone minor sentences, or sentence substitutes (therefore, requiring a period / full-stop). Or interjections, discourse markets, speech tags, word substitutes, or particles (therefore, requiring a comma)?

Can these words play different roles in different situations and hence require different punctuation?

There seems to be contradictory examples from various websites and style guides calling these words [discourse markers](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/discourse-markers-so-right-okay), [interjections](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_problem), [formulaic expressions](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/minor/formula.htm) and [pro sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-sentence).

And even a style guide / advice (below) that always mandates periods after all of these words.

[Margie Wakeman Wells: Court Reporting Resource, Books and Seminars on Good Grammar and Punctuation](http://www.margieholdscourt.com/okay-a-comma/)

> Okay is one of those words that peppers the speech patterns of many people. Here is the scoop on okay.
>
> If it comes at the beginning of a sentence, follow it with a period. It stands by itself and is not attached to anything around it.

I presume this advice only applies to free-standing "okay" and "no problem" and not when they substitute "yes"?

I would imagine that punctuation should reflect grammatical function? (Sentence substitutes should take period; interjections, word substitutes, particlesa should take commas after them.)

For example in the sentence below, would the word "okay" take comma or period?

> -- Will you help me?
>
> -- Okay (./,) I will.

Could I argue that "okay" takes comma if it stands for "yes" and period if stands for elliptical sentence "that's okay"?

What about "no problem" in the same construction?

> -- Will you help me?
>
> -- No problem(./,) I will.

Could I argue that "no problem" takes comma if it stands for "yes" and period if stands for elliptical sentence "that's not a problem"?

I am primarily interested in grammatical position (defining these words as independent constructions / clauses, requiring period, or as particles, requiring comma).

Would comma construction technically render a comma splice as it would be if the same words would be changed for "don't worry"?

> -- Will you help me?
>
> -- Don't worry, I will. (Comma splice.)

Comment: these words are never used in formal writing; they occur primarily (if not exclusively) in speech and writing that imitates speech.  hence, i'd think whether a comma or period should be used would depend on the pause between these words and what follows. (but this is a great question, and i'm eager to see whether someone has a better answer than mine.)

Comment: Two examples of how I would use the comma or the period: 
*Okay, I will help you* ---
*Okay. Oh, have you heard about the robbery last night?* ---

This reflects the actual pause in speech, which in turns reflects the fact that I'm still talking about the same thing, or not.

Comment: Use comma. Full stop will do fine, but comma works better. Both "okay" and "No problem" are interjections. Choosing between a comma and full stop is your choice. If you are using both interjections, then It would be better to put full stop first then comma: "Okay. No problem, I will help you."

Comment: Edited to make it a little bit more interesting.

Comment: @dbliss has it right. These are all conversational English. That is, one **hears** them; if one is recording speech in writing, one uses commas where one hears them, ditto periods and other full stops. If one doesn't hear them, one shouldn't be recording speech in writing.

Comment: @JohnLawler hmmm... would that then suggest different punctuation rules between formal and informal English? Where do we draw a line and how do we know when the last "don't worry" example is comma splice or colloquial construction. Just trying to understand the logic as surely punctuation rules should be identical irrespctive of the type of writing. Also the author, published court reporter, [here](http://www.margieholdscourt.com/okay-a-comma/) seems to be adamant about a period?

Comment: First, "Formal" and "informal" are very imprecise terms, and they're social, not linguistic. Second, writing is just a representation of speech, not its source. Third, there is no [set of punctuation rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf), anyway, and if there were, it wouldnt be part of grammar, but spelling. You may have noticed that people punctuate any way they please. This is because punctuation rules are all arbitrary -- especially inaudible punctuation like apostrophe's that make distinctions not present in the language itself.

Comment: There has been a post on ELU citing an article allowing comma splices in some contexts. Another has mentioned that punctuation around sentence fragments has never been prescribed in even the most prescriptive of self-styled grammars. I'd use 'Yes I will.', 'Yes, I will.',  'Yes. I will.' or even 'Yes ... I will.' depending on how I wanted it read. I don't think 'Okay I will' is available. With 'Don't worry: I will', I think the 'reason following' colon is justified.

Comment: Thanks for the response everyone. I understand that this quite subjective area but just trying to see how these would be grammatically punctuated based on Chicago or AP conventions. Gregg in the 10th edition calls these elliptical sentences mandating a period / full stop, although his examples are when these words form the whole of the response and are not followed up by explaining sentence like "I will" in which case these words take the role of "yes" logically asking for comma - hence the confusion anf question if different situations require different punctuation.

Comment: For instance, "Will you help? Okay. Let me know when you need me." sounds different from "Will you help? Okay, I will". In the latter "okay" being "yes" and former "okay" being "Yes, I will". @EdwinAshworth, would you put a period or comma in "Okay, I will" on the latter example above"?

Comment: It depends on the spoken form I was committing to paper. The full stop marks for deliberation and/or forcefulness, with a longer pause; the comma for the minimum pause I think is needed after 'Okay' (but not 'Yes') for prosodic reasons. Please be aware that we do not champion (or explain the workings of) individual style guides' recommendations at the expense of others on ELU. Often, quite the opposite.

Comment: Sure. The style guide reference was just to try to give an example of what a grammatical position could be like. Appreciate the response. So it seems that for these spoken phrases punctuation can go either way based on the pause and tone desired.

Comment: @PaulS.: Chicago or AP standards of punctuation are examples of arbitrary rules that exist to confuse  people; they are not grammar. To repeat, English punctuation or spelling is **not** part of grammar, so "grammatically punctuated" is a misnomer; one might as well ask whether something is "morally punctuated".

Comment: @JohnLawler, interesting point. But then surely there is some standards. You yourself use semicolons between independent clauses, commas within clauses. Is that arbitrary as well? How can one tell what is accepted standard and what is arbitrary rules? Also what about all those that teach "colon should only follow independent clause". Is that arbitrary as well? Can I follow my own rules in, say, academic paper? Don't get me wrong I am all for this concept of punctuation (I used to be at least), but years of prescriptive grammar lessons make you feel there is a logical rule for everything.

Comment: And make you feel you are wrong when you don't put the right mark in the right place. Would be interested to hear your view on whether it matters and why so many people insist on "standard rules" on punctuation that should be abided at all times.

Comment: @PaulS.  The wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from, all different, all contradictory, all arbitrary, all useless. "Standards" like you quote are usually more or less safe workarounds that teachers feel good passing on; but they're never general enough, and they almost always seize on precisely the wrong feature to pay attention to -- like what word or what kind of word a comma is sposta go before or after, when comma placement is simply not determined by anything like that, but by **sound**, like _a/an_. It isn't their fault; nobody taught them better.

Comment: @JohnLawler Writing is not just "a representation of speech."  Plenty of written text has never been spoken and was never intended to be.  All standards are arbitrary to some extent; that doesn't make them useless. I have noticed that some people punctuate as they please.  These people are called "illiterate."  And shame on you for citing yourself.

Comment: Is a 'discourse market' one with a lot of sales talk?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following sentences:

**"OK, we're all going to the store today," mom informed us.**

**"OK: we're all going to the store today," mom informed us.**

**"OK. We're all going to the store today," mom informed us.**

**"OK; we're all going to the store today," mom informed us.**

**"OK – we're all going to the store today," mom informed us.**

**"OK! We're all going to the store today!" mom informed us."**

**"We're going to the store today, OK?"**

Did you read the first 5 sentences the same way? This is why they're called style guides rather than grammar textbooks, but it doesn't take away the importance of having it read the way you want it to read.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You definitely read them differently, but so you also read "Don't worry. I will" and "Don't worry, I will". But the latter is not grammatical. Grammatical punctuation, based on what I have learned, is not concerned with rhetoric but with structure. Hence, I am trying to look at this from word function / structure point of view.

Comment: On another site, it says that if "okay" is the answer to an implied question, it's its own sentence and gets a cap and period. "No matter what you think we're going. Okay?" But if it simply modifies the sentence it gets a comma. "Okay, let's get on the road."

Comment: @Zan700  It's not as clear-cut as that. << "Okay. Let's get on the road." >> with _Okay_ as a sequencing / atttention-grabbing or focusing marker is quite acceptable; the full stop marks a longer, more abrupt pause in speaking.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "okay" is being used as an interjection, and should therefore be separated from the rest of the sentence by a comma for a short pause and a period for a longer one. For interjections, one can choose among a comma, period, and exclamation point. "Don't worry" and "no problem" are also being used, in this case, as interjections, so commas can work.

Personally, I'd use a comma for a very short pause, a semicolon for a longer one, and a period for a significant pause.

Comment: OP asks about the more general term 'parenthetical' here, and parentheticals may of course be used with zero offsetting punctuation in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I often use the word "sure" at the beginning of a dialog, not as an affirmation, but as an emphatic. For instance, a character says, "Sure is hot out here." In this case, a comma would make the reading a bit awkward, so I do not use one. However, if I am using the word "sure" to affirm something, I would use a comma. For instance, if my character says, "Sure, I'll go along with that," then I use the comma. Word editors like Microsoft editor and Grammarly call for a comma following "sure" regardless of the circumstances under which I use the word, so I must still make the call myself.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  "Sure is hot out here" uses an implied "it" as the subject.  Otherwise it's not clear how this brings a new answer to the question, and I encourage you to take the [tour] and see the [help].